# java - calculate Math floor

Tags: java

Hi I just came accross some legacy code, were I found one `Math.floor()` calculation
like `Math.floor(value)*100/100`. Just I trying to understand why they having that `*100/100`, because with and without this *multiplication* and *division*, I getting the same result.

Any suggesstions on why they having this calculation?
At what situation this calculation will help me?

```
public class DoubleTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double val = 6.93904587395873495873493453453453454587349458734985739487857;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(val)*100/100);
    System.out.println(Math.floor(val));
 }
}
```

**Output**

```
6.0
6.0
```

Comment: it could be typo, maybe author wanted `Math.floor(val*100)/100`

Comment: or it is not from JAVA originally and the `100` operations are on integers ... sometimes `sign*absfloor` is done this way (also to 2 places)

Comment: Well if this really is a typo like the accepted answers suggests, then I wonder why no one noticed it earlier. Aren't there any test to prove the correctness of that code?

Comment: @Tom Agreed, it is mistake happened during my understanding, but the accepted answer given me clear cut idea of what this calculation is exactly doing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is it was meant to be:

```
Math.floor(value*100)/100;
```

Which essentially rounds `value` to two decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's an error and they really wanted `Math.floor(val*100)/100.0`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted actually do nothing. But if you follow Mark Peters answer that's perfect. If you are confused about what it does actually then this is what happens:

```
Math.floor(value*100)/100;
```

1. value * 100 = 693.9045873958734958.................
2. Math.floor(value * 100) = 693
3. Math.floor(value * 100) / 100 = 693/100 = 6.93